# RecyclerView delete the wrong position item

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a list of item in RecylerView, with have a delete button with delete the item from the list.
When I click the delete button, the item at last got deleted not the item selected to be deleted.
What's more, it creates a new item with old item's data instead of new data.
The following below is the code written in Kotlin:

```
class MedicineAdapter(private val activity: Activity, private val dataSet: MutableList<MedicineModel>, private val medicineSet: List<MedicineData>): RecyclerView.Adapter<MedicineAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val deleteLayout: LinearLayout
        val medicineLayout: LinearLayout
        val medicineName: TextView
        val timeLayout: LinearLayout
        val medicineTime: TextView

        init {
            deleteLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.delete_layout)
            medicineLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.medicine_layout)
            medicineName = view.findViewById(R.id.medicine_name)
            timeLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.time_layout)
            medicineTime = view.findViewById(R.id.medicine_time)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.layout_medicine_item, viewGroup, false)

        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        viewHolder.deleteLayout.setOnClickListener {
            deleteRecord(viewHolder.adapterPosition)
        }

        viewHolder.medicineLayout.setOnClickListener {
            val spinnerDialog = SpinnerDialog(activity, medicineSet.map { p -> p.name } as ArrayList<String>, "请选择药品", "关闭")
            spinnerDialog.setCancellable(true)
            spinnerDialog.setShowKeyboard(false)
            spinnerDialog.bindOnSpinerListener { item, position ->
                viewHolder.medicineName.text = item
            }
            spinnerDialog.showSpinerDialog()
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return dataSet.count()
    }

    fun addRecord() {
        val position = dataSet.count()
        dataSet.add(position, MedicineModel())

        notifyItemInserted(position)
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    private fun deleteRecord(position: Int) {
        dataSet.removeAt(position)

        notifyItemRemoved(position)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

I have called `notifyDataSetChanged` however it does not seems to work.

Comment: You haven't ever update the `medicineName.text` and `medicineTime.text` in `onBindViewHolder`. You should update the UI with data from `dataSet[position]`

Comment: I forgot about it. After setting data to ``dataSet[position]`` everything works like a charm. Thank you so much for answering